# Publishing msi project c#

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installation, publish

We do have an application which did not have any setup (click once with updates checking, etc).
However it gives very little information for our customers when installing.
We have added Setup Project and everything works fine while installing from VS or from the folder. However, when we publish the application (local or to the web) it is still using click once. Setup.exe begins installation without loading any setup project files.
How to publish the project with the msi installer only so the installation includes setup project?
We use VS 2010 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

In C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\solution\project\bin\release there is an EXE file that contains the .exe that would need to be run (outside of the click once). If you add that to the msi when you create it, it shouldn't deploy in Click Once.

Comment: I will tell what we are doing:
1. We create the project APP1 (from scratch). One button for example. 2. The build the solution to ( APP1 debug / release) 3. Add Setup Project 4. Add files from (debug / project of APP1), build the Setup Project. 5. Click Install and everything is doing just fine or open folder containing and clicking Setup there (the same positive result). 
HOWEVER. When we click publish APP1 it does create setup file which just runs the installation and that is it (no setup files are included). But we need to have setup files and check for updates with the setup files.